Why is this Dafny Method not holding when it should?
method search(a: array<int>) returns (i : int)
  requires a.Length > 1 && a[0] == a[a.Length-1]
  ensures 0 <= i < a.Length-1 && a[i] >= a[i + 1]
{
  i := ......;
  var j := ......;
  while i != j
    invariant ......;
  {
    var m := (i + j) / 2;
    if a[....] >= a[....] {
      i := .....;
    } else {
      j := .....;

    }
  }
}

So this is a Lab question from my introduction to Dafny course at Uni. You are only allowed to modify the 5 blank spaces and add as many assertions as you need to make the method the verifiable. This is my attemp at solving it:
method search(a: array<int>) returns (i: int)
  requires a.Length > 1 && a[0] == a[a.Length-1]
  ensures 0 <= i < a.Length-1 && a[i] >= a[i+1]
{  
  i := 0;
  var j := a.Length - 2;
  while i != j
    invariant 0 <= i <= j < a.Length - 1;
  {
    var m := (i + j) / 2;

    if a[j] >= a[j + 1]{
      i := j;
      assert a[j] >= a[j + 1] && a[i] >= a[i + 1];
      assert i == j;
    } else {
      j := j - 1;
    }
  }
  
  assert 0 <= i < a.Length - 1; 
  assert a[j] >= a[j + 1] && a[i] >= a[i + 1];
}

The last assertion appears not to hold when it clearly should be holding. As this algorithm is a linear search (goes through all possibilites) and when the loop executes we actually find the correct value. The exact same assertion holds right before the loop is terminated. However, it doesn't hold outside the loop and I don't understand it. Any ideas?

This code also works when you show there is always at least 1 element in the list that does not follow increasing pattern. You can add a lemma to prove the assertion (assert exists k :: 0 <= k < a.Length-1 && a[k] >= a[k+1]) holds before the while loop or you can simply do this before the while loop: assert exists k :: 0 <= k < a.Length-1 && a[k] >= a[k+1] by {
if forall k :: 0 <= k < a.Length-1 ==> a[k] < a[k+1] {
var j := 0;
while j < a.Length-1
invariant 0 <= j < a.Length-1
invariant a[0] < a[j+1]
{
j := j + 1;
}
}
}

The correct answer was:
method search(a: array<int>) returns (i: int)
  requires a.Length > 1 && a[0] == a[a.Length-1]
  ensures 0 <= i < a.Length-1 && a[i] >= a[i+1]
{  
  i := a.Length - 2;
  var j := 0;
  while i != j
    invariant 0 <= j <= i < a.Length - 1 && a[j] >= a[i + 1]
  {
    var m := (i + j) / 2;

    if a[j] >= a[m + 1]{
      i := m;
    } else {
      j := m + 1;
    }
  }
}


Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?

To begin with Dafny does not run the code exactly. The only thing it knows outside of a loop block/method is what is specified by the invariant/ensures clauses. Currently, your loop says nothing about the relationship between a[i] and a[j] or a[i+1]. Therefore, outside of the loop all it knows is that i == j and it forgets about the work done inside the loop.
Secondly, you aren't using the variable m for anything.
They key is to think inductively, at the beginning a[i] >= a[j+1] because a[0] == a[a.Length-1], so your goal is to find relationships that will maintain that relationship going forward.
I found a couple solutions but they are not the correct solutions for the given stub because I changed around the variables being assigned in the if blocks. They should give you an idea of what you are missing, without giving away the answer.
method search(a: array<int>) returns (i: int)
        requires a.Length > 1 && a[0] == a[a.Length-1]
        ensures 0 <= i < a.Length-1 && a[i] >= a[i+1]
    {  
        i := 0;
        var j := a.Length - 2;
        while i != j
            invariant 0 <= i <= j < a.Length - 1
            invariant a[i] >= a[j + 1]
        {
            var m := (i + j) / 2;

            if a[i] >= a[m+1] {
                //assigning j instead of i
                j := m;
            } else {
                // assert a[i] >= a[j + 1];
                // assert a[i] < a[m+1];
                i := m + 1;
                // assert a[i] >= a[j + 1];
            }
        }
    }

    method search1(a: array<int>) returns (i: int)
        requires a.Length > 1 && a[0] == a[a.Length-1]
        ensures 0 <= i < a.Length-1 && a[i] >= a[i+1]
    {  
        i := 0;
        var j := a.Length - 2;
        while i != j
            invariant 0 <= i <= j < a.Length - 1
            invariant a[i] >= a[j + 1]
        {
            var m := (i + j) / 2;
            //Isn't using m

            if a[j] >= a[j + 1]{
            i := j;
            assert a[j] >= a[j + 1] && a[i] >= a[i + 1];
            assert i == j;
            } else {
            j := j - 1;
            }
        }
        
        assert 0 <= i < a.Length - 1; 
        assert a[i] >= a[i + 1];
    }


I have adjusted the code you provided such that it now fits into the format of the question. It works brilliantly. Much obliged.
